# Как правильно парсить XML в PHP?

Tags: php, json, xml, парсер

Здравствуйте, коллеги!

Есть файл выгрузки товаров в формате XML (по сути Яндекс.Маркет):
https://krutygolov.com.ua/krutygolov_rozetka.xml

Время от времени нужно менять параметр `available="true"` на false, цену и прочие мелочи. Возможно ли как-то вносить правки с помощью PHP без полной регенерации файла? Я имею в виду без do while foreach и тяжелых библиотек для работы с XML, а просто парсить содержимое файла в строку и в ней искать нужные параметры?

К примеру, перейти к строке `<offer available="true" id="1999">` и в ней изменить `<price>199</price>` не меняя больше ничего в файле.

Пока что все правки вносятся через Notepad++, есть идея создавать каждый раз файл XML парся данные из JSON. Но, походу, это не особо меняет ситуацию.

Comment: какого объема у вас файл, что нежелательно использовать библиотеки для работы с XML? и зачем вам там do-while-foreach если с помощью xpath/xquery можно сразу достать  нужный узел и изменить там значения?